# Biblatex bibliography section without title

Tags: biblatex

I need to create a bibliography section without a title in Biblatex. The only way I've found for doing that is like so:

```
\printbibliography[title={\ }]
```

but this seams a bit dirty.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `heading=none` to completely remove the title from `\printbibliography`

```
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```